# How is fix error: Trying to get property of non-object ?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want get from after click `$_POST['name']` and where it with name inserting that get row id for insert in other table, but get following error. What is the cause of the error? How to fix?

```
$name = $this -> input -> post('name');
$query_re = $this->db->get_where('tour_foreign', array('name' => $name))->row();

$data2 = array();
foreach ($residence_name as $idx => $name) {
    $data2[] = array(
        'relation' => $query_re->id, //This is line number 58
        'hotel_id' => $residence_id[$idx],
        'name' => $residence_name[$idx],
    );
};
$data222 = $this->db->insert_batch('residence', $data2);
```

Error:

> A PHP Error was encountered
>  Severity: Notice
>  Message: Trying
>   to get property of non-object
>  Filename: foreign.php
>  Line
>   Number: 58

Comment: Please identify line #58

Comment: @KorvinSzanto it's written as a comment "//this is line number 58"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that this database call returns zero rows :

```
$query_re = $this->db->get_where('tour_foreign', array('name' => $name))->row();
```

Also consider using num_rows() to check the result of the database call before calling row().

Answer (score 0):

PHP doesn't allow you to treat the return value of a function as an object, unless it returns a reference. Try

```
$where = $this->db->get_where(...);
$query_re = $where->row();
```

Edit:

Nevermind, I missed the 'line 58' comment, and I guess PHP5 allows chaining. Fancy

Comment: Actually, the chaining is allowed here

Comment: Isn't it only with php4 that is a problem?

Comment: Ugh. Yes, it appears you are both correct. Thank you for teaching me something new about php5

Answer (score 0):

Basically what the code is trying to tell you, is that you're trying to get a property of a variable which is NOT an object (an instance of a class).

So on like number 58, it's saying that $query_re is not an object, and therefore cannot have the property 'id'.

Answer (score 0):

```
$query_re = $this->db->get_where('tour_foreign', array('name' => $name))->row();
if(is_object($query_re))  {
    ....
}
```